# How to increase root partition size in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I wish to extend the root partition size without any data loss in CentOS 7. For that I searched about this on internet. I found many blogs and videos.

I tried their solutions in my spare system (for experimenting with their methods, but nothing worked for me. I got either an error or not increasing the root partition size.

See my existing partitions and their sizes.

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -hT
Filesystem                  Type        Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted On
devtmpfs                    devtmpfs    5.8G    0       5.8G    0%      /dev
tmpfs                       tmpfs       5.8G    0       5.8G    0%      /dev/shm
tmpfs                       tmpfs       5.8G    8.9M    5.8G    1%      /run
tmpfs                       tmpfs       5.8G    0       5.8G    0%      /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root     xfs         50G     1.3G    49G     3%      /
/dev/mapper/centos-home     xfs         167G    33M     167G    1%      /home
/dev/sda2                   xfs         1014M   144M    871M    15%     /boot
/dev/sda1                   xfs         200M    12M     189M    6%      /boot/efi
tmpfs                       tmpfs       1.2G    0       1.2G    0%      /run/user/0
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
Name                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE    RO  TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0     0   223.6G  0   disk    
|---sda1                8:1     0   200M    0   part    /boot/efi
|---sda2                8:2     0   1G      0   part    /boot
|---sda3                8:3     0   222.4G  0   part
    |---centos-root     253:0   0   50G     0   lvm     /
    |---centos-swap     253:1   0   5.9G    0   lvm     [SWAP]
    |---centos-home     253:2   0   166.5G  0   lvm
sr0                     11:0    1   1024M   0   rom
```

I wish to increase the CentOS root partition size from 50G to 100G, and decrease from 167G to 115G something.

---

for acheive this I tried fdisk Utility way. I [refered this blog](https://tekneed.com/increase-standard-extend-root-partition-using-fdisk/)

first i run: `fdisk /dev/sda` command

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EA436XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

#   Start   End         Size    Type        Name
1   2048    411647      200M    EFI System  EFI System Partition
2   411648  2508799     1G      Microsoft basic
3   2508800 468862094   222.4G  Linux filestyle

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-3, default 3):

Partition 3 is deleted

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-3, default 3):

First sector (34-468862094, default 2508800):
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2508800-468862094, default 468862094):

Created Partition 3

Command (m for help): w
The Partition table has been altered!

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The Kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)

Syncing disks.

[root@localhost ~]# xfs_growfs /dev/sda3
xfs_growfs /dev/sda3 is not a mounted XFS filesystem

[root@localhost ~]# xfs_growfs /
meta-data=/dev/mapper/centos-root isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=3276800 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0, spi=0,
```

I also [tried this](https://youtu.be/OLPpc17UPlU?si=TT2aPQ4cA3UZCqMc).

I read somewhere as If we have to extend root partition then we have to run CentOS from USB instead of drive disk. for Run CentOS 7 live from USB I copied CentOS 7 DVD .iso file in my bootable pen drive by using the following command:

```
sudo dd bs=512k if=/home/myuser01/Downloads/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress oflag=sync
```

After the process was completed when I run this bootable USB in my system using BIOS. There I didn't get any option related to the "Boot from local drive" ([CentOS site : Test this media & install CentOS 7](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Boot_x86/)).

.either doesn't work or I get error about related to "disk in use error".

Answer (score 2):

Your filesystems are under LVM management so you must use LVM tools to manage the space. But your filesystem of `/home` is `xfs` which mean you **can't** shrink it. You should copy all the information from `/home`, destroy `centos-home` and recreate it again with smaller size.

Comment: for e.g. If we backup all data of `/home`, and destroy `centos-home` and recreate it again with smaller size, but after that can we increase `centos-root` size without delete it?, because `centos-root` is `xfs`

Comment: @HarshPatel, yes, you can grow `centos-root` on the fly, `xfs` can grow w/o a problem

Comment: okay then can you explain me a detailed process about, first can I take back up in same disk? if I backup in same disk and then when I destroy /home at that time my backup will safe? please guide me or give references related to backup and restore after increase root partition

Comment: @HarshPatel, I do not see a way to backup on the same disk. Use external disk or storage to backup. And all this are additional questions. Please ask separate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask